# Getting NameNotFoundException while running client program of EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I am new to EJB.

I am trying to learn to develop a stateless bean. I created the jar file and deployed it on Weblogic server and then i executed the client code. I have already set the classpath for *api.jar* and *weblogic.jar*. But on running client code i am getting following error:

```
C:\Users\Asad\Desktop\EJB>java EjbClient1
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'myAdder#Adder'. Resolved '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'myAdder#Adder'. Resolved '']; remaining name 'myAdder#Adder'
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1224)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:273)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:217)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupIgnorePartition(BasicNamingNode.java:1503)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.PartitionHandler.lookupSharable(PartitionHandler.java:88)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookup(ServerNamingNode.java:584)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode.lookup(RootNamingNode.java:81)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:645)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:248)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$2.run(BasicServerRef.java:534)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:531)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:137)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'myAdder#Adder'. Resolved ''
        at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
```

Following is the code.

Client EjbClient1.java:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.naming.Context;  
import javax.naming.InitialContext;  

public class EjbClient1 {
    public static void main(String s[])throws Exception {
        Properties parm=new Properties();
        parm.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        parm.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url","t3://localhost:7001");
        parm.setProperty("java.naming.security.principal","weblogic");
        parm.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials","asad9711");
        // parm.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials","weblogic12");

        InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext(parm);
        Adder stub=(Adder)ctx.lookup("myAdder#Adder");

        int c=stub.add(10,20);
        System.out.println(c);

    }
}
```

Bean class AdderBean.java:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(mappedName="myAdder")
class AdderBean implements Adder {
    @PostConstruct  
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("post create");

    }
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy()
    {
        System.out.println("destroy");
    }
    public int add(int x,int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Remote Interface Adder.java:

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Adder
{
     int add(int x,int y);
}
```

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of your `Adder` interface, i.e., what's the package name of the interface?

Comment: All three   `.java files (Adder.java,AdderBean.java,EjbClient1.java) ` are present in the same folder.

Comment: Could you check, do you have your class files inside the jar?

Comment: Any progress you made?

Comment: I made the jar file of `Adder.java, AdderBean.java,ejb-jar.xml `.It gets successfully deployed on the weblogic server but when i execute the client(EjbClient1),it gives error.

Comment: I am confused about what files to put in jar file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108747/discussion-between-a874-and-unknown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me after changing few things.

I changed your session bean's access modifier to **public**.

Check your jar file contains the class files. It must contain your Interface and SessionBean.

[image: Screenshot with output]

With Command line

1)Compile the project

```
Project_DIR>javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib\.m2\repo
sitory\javax\javaee-api\6.0\javaee-api-6.0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.
3\server\lib\weblogic.jar src\main\java\Adder.java src\main\java\AdderBean.java
src\main\java\EjbClient1.java
```

2)Build jar

```
Project_DIR\bin>jar cf myejbapp.jar Adder.class AdderBean
.class EjbClient1.class
```

3)Deploy the myejbapp.jar to weblogic and run the EJBClient1

Answer (score 0):

try to lookup using fully qualified name
in form of (mappedName#packageName.interfaceName) even if they were in same package